# Javascript function returns false but it does not prevent postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, click

I have an ASP.NET website where a user opens up an image in a ImageButton web control. They can then click around on the imagebutton and the client-side function will calculate the "real" distance between pairs of clicks. The client-side javascript function is referenced by the OnClientClick parameter of the asp:ImageButton. The function actually works without postback when only numClick++; and document.getElementID("labelcount").innerText = numClick; are executed, but a postbakc keeps occurring when the whole function is written out. How can I fix this problem?
Here is JavaScript code:

```
var pos1x = 0, pos1y = 0;
var pos2x = 0, pos2y = 0;
var total = 0;
var distx = 0; disty = 0;
var redistx = 0, redisty = 0, newdist = 0;
var numClick = 0;
function Image_Click() {
        numClick++;
        document.getElementById("labelcount").innerText = numClick;
        if (numClick % 2 == 1)
        {
            pos1x = event.pageX;
            pos1y = event.pageY;

        }
        else if (numClick % 2 == 0)
        {
            pos2x = event.pageX;
            pos2y = event.pageY;
            distx = Math.abs(pos2x - pos1x);
            disty = Math.abs(pos2y - pos1y);
            redistx = Math.ceil(distx/50);
            redisty = Math.ceil(disty / 50);

            newdist = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(redistx * redistx + redisty * redisty));
            document.getElementById("lengthlabel").innerText = newdist;
            total += newdist;
            document.getElementById("labeltotal").innerText = total;
       }
       return false;
   }
```

Here is .aspx for ImageButton

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="pic" runat="server" ImageAlign="Left" ImageUrl="~/MemberPages/447298.jpg" OnClientClick="return Image_Click();" />
```

Comment: I am not sure what is postback but, have you tried to do: function Image_Click(e) and later in your code e.preventDefault()?

Comment: Yeah, it didn't work

Comment: my guess is there is a javascript error that prevents the code from getting to the return false. Add a debug statement and walk through the code.

Comment: It's weird because I executed the same script a few days ago with some added complexities a few days ago and it was fine. The code I posted is the simplest that didn't work today

Comment: I did some more website testing on different browsers. The script works in any browser except firefox (I think its the cache size that causes issues)